# Directfbgl with Qt-4.6.2

Tags: opengl-es, embedded-linux, directfb, qtembedded

I am using Qt-4.6.2 cross-compiled for Linux/MIPS device with directfb-1.4.14. I am trying to create overlays on top of my QT application which plays some videos. 
Recently on directfb website in [news](http://directfb.org/index.php?path=Main/News&entry=2011-09-25-0.dok), it was updated that Qt applications on DirectFB can utilise OpenGL now. Here is my question:

- Is it possible to use directfbgl with Qt-4.6.2 on Linux/MIPS device?
  If yes, how can I merge directfbgl with Qt-4.6.2 and cross-compile
  it?
- Will directfbgl application run on my hardware which does not
  support OpenGL?

Can anyone please help me?